# Spring and hibernate long term support

Tags: hibernate, java-17

We are trying to upgrade JDK 17 and hibernate needs to be 5.4.32+ for that (we are using 5.4.23 currently). But 5.4.23 and 5.4.32 both have reached end of life. The next active version is 6.3 but i could not find how long it will be supported. Please suggest.

Thanks,